# how can i compile a source code that contains different types?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, ant, compilation

I'm new in Java. I've ran a toolkit in Ubuntu. to run the toolkit, i must export Apache Ant, Apache HADOOP , SWIG and another source code. 
So, i want to compile the source code in Eclipse. The source code contains these files:
-Bin
-Class
-Data: it contains *.itg files
-Lib: it contains .jar files
-Scripts: Two files contain  *.pl and shell script
          A file contains *.py and *.sh
          A file contains *.sh , *.pl and .py
          A file contains files that include *.cpp, *.pl,*.pm

-Build.xml
-Logging.properties

please help me, which compilers can  compile these codes?

Comment: You have tons of diferents languages here... .jar are packaged java programms, .py are python scrypt, .sh are shell script, .pl are perl script and .cpp are C++ sources files. I don't really anderstand what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in text editor build.xml - probably that file contains "Apache ANT" configuration for your project.
Probably there is already ANT target that allows compilation, etc.

For ANT usage see following link: http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html